# How to reproduce standard page style in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

### Motivation

I'd like to reproduce a standard Lead conversion page style in a custom visualforce page. However, I'm seeing a number of differences.

Some are in visual style, e.g. block section titlebar:

[image]

[image]

There are also lines between rows which are not present in default style (not visible in the above pictures).

Other changes are in code produced by pages, but that could be due to code differences.

### Question

1. How can I reproduce the visual style of a standard Salesforce page like Lead Convert
2. Is `.page` source code available for standard Lead Convert page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `standardStylesheets="true"` and look into the `mode` attribute on `apex:pageBlock`.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the visual block style in visualforce, by setting the attribute `mode` to `edit` on `<apex:pageBlock>`

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
```

this will convert:
[image]

to:

[image]

as far as the code for standard pages go, I can't help you. If you needed help on converting Leads, take a look at: [ConvertLead Operation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm)

Comment: That works great! I'm upvoting your answer and accepting the earlier one which describes mode attribute.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can reproduce visual style using `tabStyle` attribute of `<apex:page>` tag.
2. As far as i know you can not have standard page source code.

Comment: I did use the appropriate tabStyle with `tabStyle="Lead"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Layout Page ?

[Layout Page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU)

Comment: It's not so useful for Lead Convert page, but it's great for standard objects. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can convert any existing layout to a VisualForce page using one of the functions of the Salesforce Enabler DataLoader plug-in to excel that can be downloaded for free at www.taralex.us